# Get objects with the most tags in common with another object in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Say I have an Image model with a many-to-many relationship with a Tag model.

Given an image, what is the optimal way to find the all the images with more than x number of tags in common with said image, and order by number of tags in common?

So for example if I have an image with tags `sand, beach, house, water, sea`
I want to find lets say all the images that have at least 2 of those tags, and then order by how many of them they have. (Basically an implementation of a similar images function using number of tags in common to define similarity)

Looking for an optimized solution here if possible, using Django's orm

Comment: Not sure how to do this with the django ORM (possible Raw SQL, or using the Q-object), but basicly what you want to do is: http://pastebin.com/mFdCK94q (pseudo SQL)
You need to query directly on the image_tag-table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
img = Image.objects.first()

Image.objects.filter(tags__in=img.tags.all()).\
  annotate(num_common_tags=Count('pk')).order_by('-num_common_tags')

# To filter out Images with < 2 common tags

Image.objects.filter(tags__in=img.tags.all()).\
  annotate(num_common_tags=Count('pk')).filter(num_common_tags__gt=2).\
  order_by('-num_common_tags')
```

Comment: This is nearly what I want, I also need to be able to define a minimum of x number of tags in common